# How to load PowerBI report url with dynamic query parameter into mvc website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iframe, powerbi

How to load PowerBI report url with dynamic query parameter into mvc website.

URL : https://{PowerBIPortalURL}/reports/{guid}/ReportSection{SectionID}?filter={}/{id} eq 'dynamic id value'

I tried with , 
But getting bellow error,

X-Frame-Options may only be set via an HTTP header sent along with a document. It may not be set inside .

Refused to display '{Some URL}' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

[image: Error In Chrome]

[image: Error in Edge]

Answer (score 0):

Before request report, you need to authenticate your request with your username and password which has permission to the report. If you are using Asp.net MVC I suggest you that install Microsoft.PowerBI.Api. It will help you to do whatever you like with powerbi in your asp.net Website.
First, install Microsoft.PowerBI.Api with the following NuGet package:

> Install-Package Microsoft.PowerBI.Api

Then you can follow the instruction in the following link:
[Microsoft.PowerBI.Api Github page](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-CSharp)